# multiple arguments on javascript function

Tags: javascript, karate

Hey so i have a javascript function in a separate file.

```
function polling_orderitem_CNCL(source_id, condition) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        var result = karate.call('./polling/get_order_item.feature', {SourceId : source_id});
        var sCode = result.response.data.attributes.statusCode;
        karate.log('poll response', greeting);
        if (greeting == condition) {
            karate.log('condition satisfied, exiting');
            return;
        }
        karate.log('sleeping');
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And im calling it in my feature file like so

```
* def waitUntil_CNCL = read('./polling/polling_orderitem_CNCL.js')
* call waitUntil_CNCL(ciSourceId, 'CNCL')
```

While running it i get the following error

```
[ERROR] Scenario: Get order and orderitem and verifications  Time
elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR
java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: 'CNCL')
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException:
<eval>:1:6 Expected ; but found )
'CNCL')
```

Comment: Um `java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);` im confused. Java inside js?!

Comment: yeah im kinda confused as well but i kinda got it from here
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the docs. Instead of using `call` you can "invoke" a function just like in "normal" JS: https://github.com/intuit/karate#js-function-argument-rules-for-call

Try this:

```
* eval waitUntil_CNCL(ciSourceId, 'CNCL')
```